# Create an array of e-mails once checkbox is clicked

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently creating an e-mail section in my admin portal. I've configured it all up to the point of being able to send out to multiple e-mails. Now I want to automate this process.

Once an Admin selects "All Users" check box, I want it to e-mail to all users. This will need to be done through an array of users being created. I have the code for that, which is

```
<?php

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email FROM cadets ORDER BY id ASC");
  $cadetEmailList = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  array_push($cadetEmailList, $row['email']);
} 

print_r($cadetEmailList)

?>
```

Now I have my array of e-mails. How do I use this array as the value once the "All Users" box is selected?

```
  <tr>
  <th>Recipients List</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="basic_checkbox_2" class="filled-in" name="all_cadets" /><label for="basic_checkbox_2">All Cadets</label></td>
```

My short-hand logic goes something like... If checkbox selected, push all emails into array variable.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['all_cadets'])) { send to all cadets } else { send to specified cadets }`

Comment: @Nick Ah, thank you! This worked perfectly. Seems simple enough. I've been at this all day, brain was dead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mailAllCadets=isset($_POST['all_cadets']) ? $_POST['all_cadets'] : "";

if ($mailAllCadets) {
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email FROM cadets ORDER BY id ASC");
  $mailList = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($mailList, $row['email']);
    $mailList = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $mailList);
    $mailList = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", ";", $mailList);
  }
  if (strpos($mailTo, ";") !== false) {
    $mailTo = explode(";", $mailTo);
  }
  var_dump($mailList);
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($mailList); $i++) {
  //  $mail->AddAddress($mailList[$i]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Since `all_cadets` is a checkbox, its value is guaranteed to be `1` if it is present in `$_POST` as it won't be present if it was not checked. So you can simplify to `$mailAllCadets = isset($_POST['all_cadets']);`